# Shifted integral for a Bessel Function

Tags: contour-integration, bessel-functions

I have an integral of the kind

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{- d \cosh(x+i a)} dx $

where $d, a \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, I know that

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{- d \cosh{x}} dx = 2 K_0(d)$

and I would like to express my integral in terms of bessel functions. However, if I deform the contour to obtain the second integral, the two vertical pieces will give me a contribution that doesn't vanish (it's possile to check this numerically as well, these two integral are not the same).
Is there a way to express the first integral in terms of bessel functions? Or at least find an asymptotic form for the large $d$ behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

No, the integral remains analytically and numerically the same as far as you keep $d$ real and positive and continuously deform $a$. However, it will become divergent as you will approach the lines $\Re{a}=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Actually the general answer (say, for $d\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$) is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-d\cosh(x+ia)}dx=
\begin{cases}
2K_0(d), & \text{for } \Re{a}\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right),\\
\text{divergent} & \text{for }\Re{a}\in\left(\;\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\;,\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right),
\end{cases}$$
with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ labeling different strips of convergence and divergence.

Comment: I agree with this result.  Nevertheless, some quick (mindless?) experimentation in Mathematica produced different results; I think I used $d=a=1$.  Anyway, food for thought for now.

Comment: @RonGordon Hi Ron, it's been a while... No, actually the Mathematica result is *exactly* the same with $a=d=1$.

Comment: Huh.  Wow, then I must have done something before my morning tea.  I'll check again, and thank heavens all is right in the universe.  (Has it been a while?  I guess I've been a little quiet.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried as well to compute it numerically with mathematica but setting a=0 gives you a real result, a=1 gives you a complex result.
And why would the integral be the same if you deform the contour?

Comment: @bnado Can you copypaste in a comment what exactly you ask Mathematica? Because for me it gives exactly the same answer, just as it should be. The reason for this is that the integrand has no singularities in the whole complex plane, and rapidly decays in the strip $|\Im x|<\pi/2$ as $\Re x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Comment: @O.L.
NIntegrate[E^-Cosh[t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
NIntegrate[E^-Cosh[t + I], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
the result is 0.842049 for the first one and 0.464606 - 0.214676 I for the second one

Comment: @bnado this is strange, because on my laptop the copypaste of these two commands in Mathematica produces 0.842049 in both cases (checked 30 seconds ago).

Comment: @O.L. It's wierd, I tried on different computers and I still got the same result. Which version of Mathematica do you have? However, I just tried to put a different method of integration, and if I use NewtonCotesRule or TrapezoidalRule (even though it gives me a warning with this last one) I actually get the same result for the shifted integral. So yeah, I guess you were right! Thanks

Comment: @bnado Mathematica 7.0. I have no guess on the origin of the second answer you're getting.